# Configuration by Exception vs Convention over Configuration

Tags: convention-over-configur

Does anybody know the difference between those two terms? In my opinion both refer to exactly the same thing: a framework or API, for which only unconventional behavior must be specified. If there is a difference, could you share with example, in which one term is acceptable, and second one not?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO both refers to the same. Nice examples to it are Maven and JPA.